# Why is Android recreating my Google MapFragment if I swipe past two tabs? [VIEWPAGER]

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-viewpager

Okay, so I have three tabs in my app:
Tab 1, Tab 2, and Tab 3.

Tab 3 contains my MapFragment with a precise location set in Asia. When I swipe to tab 2 from tab 3 and swipe back to tab 3 everything works fine. But if I swipe to tab 3, go back to tab 1, and then return to tab 3, everything is completely reset and my custom location is also reset. What's causing this issue? Any help would be appreciated. Here's my code:

```
public class MapViewActivity extends Fragment implements
        OnItemSelectedListener {

    // Google Map
    private GoogleMap googleMap;
    private Spinner spinner;
    private View view;
    private static final LatLng KABUL = new LatLng(34.31, 69.11);

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        setUpMapIfNeeded();
    }

    private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
        if (googleMap == null) {
            googleMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                    .getMap();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // getActivity().getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        // Look up the AdView as a resource and load a request.
        AdView adView = (AdView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);
        setRetainInstance(true);
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.map_layout, container, false);

        try {
            // Loading map
            initilizeMap();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        spinner = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        // Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner
        // layout
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                getActivity().getBaseContext(), R.array.map_type_array,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        // Apply the adapter to the spinner
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {

        Fragment f = (Fragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        if (f != null) {
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(f).commit();
        }

        super.onDestroyView();
    }


    /**
     * function to load map. If map is not created it will create it for you
     * */
    private void initilizeMap() {
        if (googleMap == null) {
            googleMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

            // check if map is created successfully or not
            if (googleMap == null) {
                Crouton.makeText(getActivity(), "Unable to create map",
                        Style.ALERT).show();
            }

            googleMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
            googleMap.getUiSettings().setScrollGesturesEnabled(false);
            Marker Kabul = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(KABUL));
            googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(KABUL, 6));

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        EasyTracker.getInstance(getActivity()).activityStart(getActivity()); // Add
                                                                                // this
                                                                                // method.
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        EasyTracker.getInstance(getActivity()).activityStop(getActivity()); // Add
                                                                            // this
                                                                            // method.
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {

        String itemSelected = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
        System.out.println(itemSelected);

        if (itemSelected.equalsIgnoreCase("Normal")) {
            googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
        }
        if (itemSelected.equalsIgnoreCase("Satellite")) {
            googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);
        }
        if (itemSelected.equalsIgnoreCase("Terrain")) {
            googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN);
        }
        if (itemSelected.equalsIgnoreCase("Hybrid")) {
            googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

This is the code for the class that contains all of the tabs:

```
public class FragmentContainerActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    ViewPager viewPager = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.viewpager);
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        viewPager.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(fragmentManager));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = this.getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
            return true;

        case R.id.action_send_feedback:
            Intent sendFeedbackIntent = new Intent(
                    android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            sendFeedbackIntent.setType("plain/text");
            sendFeedbackIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,
                    getResources().getStringArray(R.array.to_email));
            sendFeedbackIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,
                    getString(R.string.action_extra_subject));
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendFeedbackIntent,
                    getString(R.string.action_send_feedback)));
            return true;

        case R.id.action_about:
            Intent actionAboutIntent = new Intent(this, AboutActivity.class);
            startActivity(actionAboutIntent);
            return true;

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
}

class MyAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    Fragment fragment = null;

    public Fragment getItem(int i) {
        if (i == 0) {
            fragment = new Tab1Activity();
        }
        if (i == 1) {
            fragment = new Tab2Activity();
        }
        if (i == 2) {
            fragment = new Tab3Activity();
        }
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        if (position == 0) {
            return "Tab 1";
        }
        if (position == 1) {
            return "Tab 2";
        }
        if (position == 2) {
            return "Tab 3";
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: which Pager are you using try using this : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.html since it saves the Pages.

Comment: @ItzikSamara Yup, that's the one I'm using!

Comment: @ItzikSamara Let me post the code for the class that contains that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because ViewPager is storing only two `Fragments` by default.
Set more for correctly work:

```
viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);
```

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much!!!! I was struggling with this for days. You're a lifesaver man :D

Comment: Enjoy your check mate :)

Comment: Better practice would be to not recreate the fragment if it is already been opened. Checking if savedInstanceState==null